# why `dpkg -l | grep package` is showing a package after being purged

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, dpkg

To uninstall a package (Ex: tor) installed from repository one should use

```
sudo apt-get remove tor
```

I did this but `dpkg -l | grep tor` shown something against the package. Next I try

```
sudo apt-get purge tor
```

But when I check `dpkg -l | grep tor` I got,

```
reza@reza-N43JM:/$ dpkg -l tor    
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
un  tor            <none>         (no description available)
```

I think when I uninstall any package I should not get anything in `dpkg -l` list. Is it true? Or `apt-get remove` or `purge` does another work but not uninstall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the first [two letters](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) of the output of `dpkg -l tor` which says `un`

```
u: Unknown (an unknown state)
n: Not- The package is not currently installed
```

sometimes `dpkg` keeps such entries for references. To remove those problematic entries, run in terminal,

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

From [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg.1.html)

```
--clear-avail
          Erase  the  existing  information  about   what   packages   are
          available.
```

Comment: Using `sudo dpkg --clear-avail` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Neither for me. (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @souravc has only part of the solution.

(Note: I'm doing this on Debian, I guess it should mostly apply to Ububtu as well.)

/var/lib/dpkg/status and /var/lib/dpkg/available hold information about packages that are either available for installing (sort of what apt does), installed or just have leftover config files.  If one of these packages (say, `bar`) `Depends:` on package `foo`, but `foo` itself is already not listed (this should not happen as long as you use only official stable Debian/Ubuntu repos) `dpkg -l tor` will mention them.

`grep-status` (no root required) is a neat command that can help you locate which package is the culprit:

```
$ grep-status foo
Package: bar
Depends: foo
...
$ dpkg -s bar
$ dpkg -L bar
...
```

now you can uninstall or purge the package using eg.:

```
# dpkg -r bar
# dpkg -P bar
```